# Pandas - How to replace those exception values with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

There is a `DataFrame` like this:

```
           cost
0   8762.000000
1   -1
2   7276.000000
3   9574.000000
4   -1
..          ...
59  5508.000000
60  7193.750000
61  5927.333333
62  -1
63  4972.000000
```

The `-1` is the exception value in this case, so how to replace `-1` with `NaN`. And then how to interpolate NaN for replacement.

After that, the `DataFrame` was cleaned.But there may be some abnormal high and low values of the `DataFrame`, and then how to interpolate abnormal high and low values for replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For replace `-1` to interpolate values use replacement to `NaN`s with [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df['cost'] = df['cost'].replace(-1, np.nan).interpolate()
```

If need remove also outliers (abnormal high and low values) you can identify them by [`Series.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) and [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and replace them to `NaN`s in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) (first replace `-1`):

```
print (df)
             cost
0     8762.000000
1       -1.000000
2     7276.000000
3   957400.000000
4       -1.000000
59    5508.000000
60    7193.750000
61      59.333333
62      -1.000000
63    4972.000000

df['cost'] = df['cost'].replace(-1, np.nan)

q_low = df["cost"].quantile(0.01)
q_hi  = df["cost"].quantile(0.99)

m = df["cost"].between(q_low, q_hi, inclusive=False)

df['cost'] = df['cost'].where(m).interpolate()
print (df)
           cost
0   8762.000000
1   8019.000000
2   7276.000000
3   6686.666667
4   6097.333333
59  5508.000000
60  7193.750000
61  6453.166667
62  5712.583333
63  4972.000000
```